# Factory Object for different objects types

Tags: c++, c++11

Suppose to have the following class structure:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Base
{
  public:
    virtual ~Base<T, U>(){};
    virtual U show() = 0;

  protected:
    T foo;
};

class DerivateA : public Base<int, int>
{
  public:
    DerivateA() { foo = 7; };
    virtual int show() override { return foo; };
};

class DerivateB : public Base<std::string, std::string>
{
  public:
    DerivateB() { foo = "Hello"; };
    virtual std::string show() override { return foo; };
};
```

Is there any way I can create a factory object with a `Create()` function that, based on an input value, returns a pointer to either `DerivateA` or `DerivateB`?

Comment: Do you know that `DerivateB` and `DerivateA` do not have a common base class as template classes with different parameters create new unique classes ?

Comment: Yes, they are different objects due to template specialization.

Comment: Why you have T and U, they are same in your examples, if they can be different your factory method "Create()" can also be templated and return exact type instead of common base class, as you have different base class based on template parameters.

Comment: They will be different in the actual implementation

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood your issue correctly, but it could be smth like:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class Base
{
protected:
    explicit Base(T arg) : foo{std::move(arg)} {}

public:
    virtual ~Base<T, U>() = default;
    virtual U show() = 0;

protected:
    T foo;
};

template<typename T>
class Derivate : public Base<T, T>
{
    using base_type = Base<T, T>;
public:
    explicit Derivate(const T& arg) : base_type(arg) { };
    T show() override { return base_type::foo; };
};

class Factory
{
public:
    template<typename T>
    static Derivate<T>* create(const T& arg)
    { return new Derivate<T>{arg}; }
};
```

and we could use it like:

```
Base<int, int>* d1 = Factory::create(3);
Base<string, string>* d2 = Factory::create(string{"string"});
```

Comment: Thank you, but I think it does not work. The issue is that here `create(const T& arg)` arg is of different type than `T`.

Comment: Please, provide the example how would you use it and what would you expect.